# Openlayers 3 Base layers showing strips on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, openlayers, openlayers-3

Just today I found this bug. It shows strips on baselayers. The image below shows how it looks in OpenStreet map and Mapbox. The strips are not there on Firefox. 
My Chrome version is 59.0.3071.109 (Official Build) (64-bit). 
My Openlayers version is 3.20.1
Is there any fix for it?
[image: OpenStreetMap]
[image: OpenStreetMap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason for this is raster reprojection. If your base layer is in a different projection than your view, OpenLayers will reproject the images of the tile source.

But the particular issue you are seeing was fixed in v4.0.0 (see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/6344). So upgrading to a newer version will resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did switch my ol map to 4326. Now I switched back to the default projection. I couldn't upgrade to 4.0 as it is not yet supported by GeoExt. I will wait a bit.